# What Python regex can validate this type of string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm having trouble validating this type of input strings in Python.

The weekday have a variable number of characters.

```
Regular: 16Mar2009(mon), 17Mar2009(tues), 18Mar2009(wed)
Regular: 20Mar2009(fri), 21Mar2009(sat), 22Mar2009(sun)
Rewards: 26Mar2009(thur), 27Mar2009(fri), 28Mar2009(sat)
```

I want to validate the whole line, every line should have this specific format:

```
<name>: <date>(<weekday>), <date>(<weekday>), <date>(<weekday>)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be a little more specific. What do you want to validate? Each line? Each date segment? Just the weekday names? The whole thing as a single unit? et cetera.

Comment: Clarified the problem right now, look again at the question. sorry

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
if re.search(r"[\d]{1,2}[a-z]{3}[\d]{4}\([a-z]{3,4}\)", string, re.IGNORECASE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ5hT6/1)

Comment: it wasn't me who downvoted, but i had test this regex and it doesn't worked as expected. Example `Regular 20Mar2009(fri) 21Mar2009(sat) 22Mar2009(sun)` matched, and shouldn't, because of the lack of ":" and ","